# How to add Recycler item SetOnClickListener in javatechig example

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add **onclicklistener** for this `RecyclerView` but i tryied everything and it doesnt work!:

**FeedItem:**

```
public class FeedItem {
    private String title;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String date;
    private String tags;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void getDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(String tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

}
```

**FeedListRowHolder:**

```
public class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView thumbnail;
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView date;
    protected TextView tags;

    public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        this.tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagsItems);
    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedListRowHolder> {

    private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public FeedListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        return new FeedListRowHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedListRowHolder feedListRowHolder, int i) {
        FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getThumbnail())
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbnail);

        feedListRowHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTitle()));
        feedListRowHolder.date.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getDate()));
        feedListRowHolder.tags.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getTags()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

How we can add `OnClickListener` to this `RecyclerView`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to click whole list item? or any specific item in the list?

Comment: just all of them for show their details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Write on OnCreate method

```
 recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(
                    new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                            FeedItem bookScreenDateEntity = (FeedItem)yourList.get(position);

                            bookScreenDateEntity.getServiceid();

                        }
                    })
            );
```

**RecyclerItemClickListener class:**

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
        private OnItemClickListener mListener;

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        }

        GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

        public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {

            View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `RecyclerItem` clickable like this

```
public class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected ImageView thumbnail;
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView date;
    protected TextView tags;

    public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        this.tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagsItems);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do you stuff here
            }
      });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the View.OnClickListener in RecyclerView.ViewHolder. If you want to listen the whole item click. See below the modified viewholder class

```
public class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected ImageView thumbnail;
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView date;
    protected TextView tags;

    public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        this.tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagsItems);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Let's do this. If you want the individual view click then register each button or view click into this view holder.For example thumbnail click can register as below.

```
public class FeedListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    protected ImageView thumbnail;
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView date;
    protected TextView tags;

    public FeedListRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        this.tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagsItems);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to handle this, However one of them is given below

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // do whatever
      }
    })
);
```

RecyclerItemClickListener implementation:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;


public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
  private OnItemClickListener mListener;

  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
  }

  GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

  public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
      @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
      mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildPosition(childView));
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }
}
```